# How to apply MVC in Windows application?

Tags: windows, model-view-controller

I applied MVC (Model View Control) in web application but I never applied MVC on Windows application.

How can I apply it in a Windows application? If any good link?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: C#, and vb.net both... i can work both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the following series: [The Build Your Own CAB Series Table of Contents](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2007/07/25/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When designing windows applications (at least if you plan to use WPF) I think you should use the [Model-View-ViewModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) design pattern, as recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest: http://www.springframework.net/

But here's as good a place to start as well: http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/

Comment: The question was about MVC in windows application, not asp.net mvc

Comment: No Sriranga, I am asking about MVC in windows application

Comment: what are desktop apps and windows apps, you mean to say desktop application and windows application?

Comment: Exactly.. there is no such thing called a "windows app". A "windows" app can either be a desktop app that runs on windows or a web app that can be hosted on windows servers. :-/